# Iterate through nested GIMP groups to retrieve an array of layers

Tags: python, plugins, layer, gimp

I'm new to python and writing GIMP plugins. I'm trying to write a simple plugin to perform search/replace on layer names. I've managed to get it working with a 'flat' gimp image, but can't figure out how to get it working iteratively through groups. Here's my code for the 'flat' structure:

```
import math
import string
import re
from gimpfu import *
from array import array

def python_search_replace_layer_names(image, layer, searchterm, replaceterm, applyvisible, casesensative) :
    pdb.gimp_image_undo_group_start(image)
    pdb.gimp_context_push() 

    applylayers = []
    for layer in image.layers[::-1]:
        if (applyvisible == 0) or (layer.visible != 0): #user didn't check Only apply visible or if layer is visible.
            applylayers.append([layer,counter])

    for applylayer in applylayers:
        if casesensative == 0:
            searchtermRegEx = re.compile(re.escape(searchterm),re.IGNORECASE)
        else:
            searchtermRegEx = re.compile(re.escape(searchterm))     
        layername = searchtermRegEx.sub(replaceterm, str(applylayer[0].name))
        applylayer[0].name = layername  

    pdb.gimp_context_pop()
    pdb.gimp_image_undo_group_end(image)
    pdb.gimp_displays_flush()

register(
    "python_fu_search_replace_layer_names",
    "Search/Replace in Layer Names",
    "Search/Replace in Layer Names...",
    "stigzler",
    "stigzler",
    "2020",
    "<Image>/Edit/Search and Replace/Replace Layer Names...",
    "RGB*, GRAY*", 
    [
    (PF_STRING, "searchterm", "Search for Term:", "SearchTerm"),
    (PF_STRING, "replaceterm", "Replace With:", "ReplaceWith"),
    (PF_TOGGLE, "applyvisible",   "Only Apply to visible layers:", 0),
    (PF_TOGGLE, "casesensative",   "Case sensative:", 0)
    ],
    [],
    python_search_replace_layer_names)

main()
```

I'm guessing this is going to involve some iterative, self-referencing functions, but I'm down on three bits of knowledge:

1. The relevant plugin structure operation
2. Not knowing python's syntax/structure (normally .net, although I'm sure there's lots of similarities)
3. Not knowing the gimp api to access group structures.

Hope someone can help!

---

UPDATE:

Thanks to xenoid's answer, got this solved. If you're here looking for a layer rename pluging, you can find the finished one [here](https://magoarcade.org/wp/gimp-plugin-search-and-replace-in-layer-names/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually pretty simple. Some code I wrote to dump the layer hierarchy of an image:

```
def dump(parent,level,dumpList):
    prefix='     '*level
    for pos,layerOrGroup in enumerate(parent.layers):
        dumpList.append(prefix+layerOrGroup.name)
        if isinstance(layerOrGroup,gimp.GroupLayer):
            dump(layerOrGroup,level+1,dumpList)

def dumpLayerHierarchy(image):
    dumpList=[]
    dump(image,0,dumpList)
    gimp.message('\n'.join(dumpList))
```

The two things to know:

- A layer group is an instance of `gimp.GroupLayer` (a regular layer is `gimp.Layer`)
- duck-typing at its best, both `gimp.Image` and `gimp.GroupLayer` have their children in a `layers` attribute, so you don't even need to special-case the first level where you start with the image itself.

PS: better registration:

```
register(
    "search-replace-layer-names",
    "Search/Replace in Layer Names",
    "Search/Replace in Layer Names...",
    "stigzler",
    "stigzler",
    "2020",
    "Replace Layer Names...",
    "*", 
    [
    (PF_IMAGE,"image", "Image:", None),
    (PF_DRAWABLE, "drawable", "Drawable:", None),
    (PF_STRING, "searchterm", "Search for Term:", "SearchTerm"),
    (PF_STRING, "replaceterm", "Replace With:", "ReplaceWith"),
    (PF_TOGGLE, "applyvisible",   "Only Apply to visible layers:", 0),
    (PF_TOGGLE, "casesensative",   "Case sensative:", 0)
    ],
    [],
    python_search_replace_layer_names
    menu="<Image>/Edit/Search and Replace/"
)
```

Changes:

- Cosmetic: make the "atom" more standard. "python-fu" added by Gimp anyway
- Change menu declaration to non-deprecated type, with seperate menu item and menu location
- Make the image type `"*"` to support all image types (your code wouldn't work on indexed images)
- Make the Image and Drawable parameters explicit. This is sometimes useful. Since you likely don't use the layer/drawable anyway you can remove it from the parameters list (and from your function prototype).

Other:

- You don't need context push/pop since you don't alter the context
- You don't need to copy the image layers (`image.layers[::-1]`) or even to reverse them since you just update attributes (if you were deleting layers it would be a different matter)
- Undo-group is good, but you can bracket your code in a try/except so in case of problem the undo group is properly closed and you can still easily undo the partial changes:

```
import traceback # To still get source code location

def the_plugin(image,layer):
    image.undo_group_start()
    try:
       # Your code goes here
    except Exception as e:
        trace(e.args[0])
        gimp.message(e.args[0]+':'+traceback.format_exc())
    image.undo_group_end()
```

Your code, fixed:

```
import re,traceback
from gimpfu import *

def python_search_replace_layer_names(image,searchterm, replaceterm, applyvisible, casesensitive) :

    image.undo_group_start()

    try:
        searchtermRegEx = re.compile(re.escape(searchterm),0 if casesensitive else re.IGNORECASE)
        renameLayers(image,searchtermRegEx,replaceterm,applyvisible)  

    except Exception as e:
        gimp.message(e.args[0]+':'+traceback.format_exc())  

    image.undo_group_end()

def renameLayers(parent,searchtermRegEx,replaceterm,applyvisible):

    for pos,layerOrGroup in enumerate(parent.layers):
        if not applyvisible or layerOrGroup.visible:
            layerName = searchtermRegEx.sub(replaceterm, layerOrGroup.name)
            layerOrGroup.name = layerName

        if isinstance(layerOrGroup,gimp.GroupLayer):
            renameLayers(layerOrGroup,searchtermRegEx,replaceterm,applyvisible)

register(
    "search-replace-layer-names",
    "Search/Replace in Layer Names",
    "Search/Replace in Layer Names...",
    "stigzler",
    "stigzler",
    "2020",
    "Replace Layer Names...",
    "*", 
    [
        (PF_IMAGE,"image", "Image:", None),
        (PF_STRING, "searchterm", "Search for Term:", "SearchTerm"),
        (PF_STRING, "replaceterm", "Replace With:", "ReplaceWith"),
        (PF_TOGGLE, "applyvisible",   "Only Apply to visible layers:", 0),
        (PF_TOGGLE, "casesensitive",   "Case sensative:", 0)
    ],
    [],
    python_search_replace_layer_names,
    menu="<Image>/Edit/Search and Replace/")

main()
```

Fixes:

- add missing comma at end of `python_search_replace_layer_names` in the registration
- added `traceback` import
- removed call to `trace` function (only in my own code)
- removed many unnecessary imports
- removed `layer` parameter to plugin function
- removed `level` parameter to recursive function
- some code made more pythonic

Also, a layer in a group can be invisible either because it is itself invisible (`layer.visible` is false) or because the group is invisible. Your current code doesn't consider group-induced invisibility.

Last, some hints to debug Gimp python scripts (with some emphasis on Windows) can be found [here](https://www.gimp-forum.net/Thread-Debugging-python-fu-scripts-in-Windows).

Comment: Brilliant answer, thanks xenoid. However, I just cannot get this to work. I've re-authored my original code taking some of the ideas in your post, but no dice. I'm using a text editor to gimp, so no step debugging! ouch. WOuld be grateful if you could post some working code. As I said, python is not my native language, so there could be a lot of nuances I'm missing. Updated code in my original post.

Comment: Total awesomeness, thanks xenoid. So, I learn a few things: python doesn't like spaces (beware copy and paste) and beware missed colons! Gotta say - it's quite a neat language. Also allowed me to add some new functionality. See here for plugin: https://magoarcade.org/wp/gimp-plugin-search-and-replace-in-layer-names/

Comment: Bad idea to save the plugin to: `C:\Program Files\GIMP 2\lib\gimp\2.0\plug-ins`. It should be added in the user profile instead.

Comment: Yeah - i looked for that in C:\Users\[me] but couldn't find a .gimp folder (with show hidden files on).

Comment: `Edit>Preferences>Folders>Plugins`: that lists two directories, the one you mentioned and another one in your files (on Windows, somewhere in AppData IIRC). Use that one.

Comment: Blimey - I'd never have found that - I never look in Roaming! Thanks again.

Comment: @stigzler *I never look in Roaming!* - You should, this is the permanent part of your profile data, the one that is copied to the central server and made available to all workstations you log in, when you use "public" workstations.

Comment: ah - I live and learn! And hence that's why the plugin should be there, I'm guessing. So it can be accessed from any client running gimp.